# From an Json Object, I am trying to extract the values by using the below code in JSR223 processor

Tags: jmeter, json

```
{
        "service": "CURBSIDE",
        "unavailableLines": {
            "unavailableLine": [
                {
                    "unavailableQty": "10.0",
                    "itemLineId": "4",
                    "unavailableReasonCode": "NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                },
                {
                    "unavailableQty": "5.0",
                    "itemLineId": "3",
                    "unavailableReasonCode": "NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "HD2",
        "deliveries": {
            "delivery": [
                {
                    "serviceItemId": "SGR40400002",
                    "deliveryId": "1",
                    "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
                },
                {
                    "serviceItemId": "SGR40400003",
                    "deliveryId": "2",
                    "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
                },
                {
                    "serviceItemId": "SGR40400002",
                    "deliveryId": "3",
                    "unitOfMeasure": "ORDERS"
                }
            ]
        },
        "earliestShipDate": "2018-12-03T07:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

The above is an JSON Object. I am trying to extract the values by using the below code in JSR223 processor:

```
//dumps the json object into an element
json_str = json.dumps(newJson3)

//load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(json_str)
//print the resp
log.info(resp)

//extract an element in the response
print (resp['unavailableQty'])
```

I am getting error response, kindly some one help me to reterive all the values from the Json Object

Find the error that I am getting while using the below script

```
json_str = json.dumps(newJson3)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
log.info(resp)
print (resp['unavailableQty'])
```

Error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: 
========Error================================================
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such 
property: json for class: Script622 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12] at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171] –
```

Comment: What does `log.info(resp)` return, and what is your error message?

Comment: Your JSON Object ends with a "]" - a spelling mistake or an error in your input?

Comment: that is missed by me the json Starts with "["

Comment: @ThamilvendanPerumal could you fix the JSON in your question to correct?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the logic wrong

JSON.dump creates a string while JSON.loads creates an object

so you are creating a string from json object and then converting it back to json object

and also you are calling resp['unavailableQty'], but if the resp is the json that you have given, then it does not have a direct property field 'unavailableQty'.

To get it ,

you can directly call

```
newJson3[0].unavailableLines.unavailableLine[0].unavailableQty
```

or in the same code,

```
resp[0].unavailableLines.unavailableLine[0].unavailableQty
```

**Note:**

There are two fields with **unavailableQty**

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). Add this Post Pricessor as a child of request that returns JSON.

Specify:

- Names of created variables: `yourVariableName`
- JSON Path Expression: `$.[0].unavailableLines.unavailableLine[0].unavailableQty`
- Match no: `1`

To get first unavailableQty use this JSON Path:

```
$.[0].unavailableLines.unavailableLine[0].unavailableQty
```

To get all unavailableQty use *:

```
$.[0].unavailableLines.unavailableLine[*].unavailableQty
```

Check this:

- [JMeter Extract and Re-use as Variable](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/09/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)
- [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://jsonpath.com/?) - to test JSONPaths
- [JSON Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/) - to see the structure of JSON

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response,  the above is not the response, it is an Json Object I am getting from an third party system so now i have to extract all the values inside the object

Comment: Ok. Could you say what error did you get?

Comment: Pls find the error that I am getting while using the below script  json_str = json.dumps(newJson3)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
log.info(resp)
print (resp['unavailableQty']) javax.script.ScriptException: ========Error================================================javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: json for class: Script622
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]